# VScode: how to setup for local edit and ftp-deplyment

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code, asp-classic

I used to use Dreamweaver. I've a huge Classic ASP website. I edit the files on my local system, and when done, I can upload the file(s) via ftp to the remote webserver. Now, I try to switch to VSCode. I've installed ftp-simple, ftp-sync and deploy. But can't find the set-up to get a Dreamweaver like behaviour. Eg, I have to locate for each file I want to upload/deploy, the exact location in the remote file tree.

Answer (score 1):

I really feel like **deploy** deserves more attention. I spent the past 4 days or so to find an extension that does just that. Auto-upload to an ftp-folder from a local folder. I wanted to make git work for my website, but couldn't get that to work on the server with ftp-simple or ftp-sync because those extensions only download the opened files or open in a different temporary folder each time. I set up deploy now and got exactly what I wanted thanks to your tiny comment, thank you!

(I'm sorry if this post is too old to comment on, but I browsed Stack overflow for days to find this, so I thought it might help others in the future to point this out.)

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like your just missing your mapping configuration. Most text editor FTP packages include a configuration file where you specify the server, your credentials, and the root folder of your ftp server. Have you specified this?

Comment: Yes, I did for ftp-simple. Butfor each upload I had to navigate tot the exact location in the remote file tree. Not very handy. Today, I’ve had more luck with package ‘deploy’, which now does more or less what I was looking for. Thank you.